# Multiple accounts on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts, multiple-accounts

OK. So I have sinned and here I am at the confessional.

Yes, the mods wern't too happy about it but I made a suggestion to one mod. How about pulling in all my various accounts under this IP and rolling them into one. It's a pain not having the back-log of questions I can refer to if there are things that I'd like to go back and look at without accidentally duping questions.

Or is this too much to ask. The mod in question suggested it could be a 'good' idea.

Any pointers?

Comment: Assuming you created all those accounts to bypass a question ban, merging all of them (while the right thing to do) is definitely gonna keep you banned. But that's sort of a separate issue.

Comment: There's too many to count for this - I can't possibly remember all their names. But I do know the logs will have a record of everything thats been said and done on my IP address. Obviously I do not have superuser status to undertake such an audit though.

Comment: @Mysticial I know, but I'm willing to sit out the ban. It expires in 48 hours anyway.

Comment: A suspension and a ban are different things. A suspension times out, a ban doesn't.

Comment: What type of ban? Question bans never expire. You need you dig yourself out of them. Suspensions do.

Comment: Suspension - yes. But I have had a bunch of my accounts wiped out when the the blood hounds were released. I would quite like their question history back as it was a genuinely helpful record of information.

Comment: If some of them were deleted, it's probably unlikely you'll get them back. You can merge those that still exist.